# ferrite bead selection for GSM application

Tags: ferrite-bead

I am trying to get a better understanding of a good method for selecting ferrite beads from those available.

I have a CLC filter, with 1uF x7r ceramics for each C, L being a ferrite bead in a 0805 package. Following this a LDO regulator that may need to supply 80mA peak of regulated supply. There is a GSM antenna operating from 850-2100MHz a few cm away, which is why there is additional filtering at the input of the LDO which is a noise sensitive 3V rail (10uF + 1uF + 0.1uF + 47pF on output). Assuming we are not going to change this arrangement, could you make some suggestion on how to select this part?

I have read guidelines of specifying the load to be no more than 20% of its rated current. [This is the ferrite bead I am currently looking at](https://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/742792097.pdf). How would this [other ferrite bead compare, since it has a very different profile?](https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/productdetail.aspx?cate=luNoiseSupprFilteChipFerriBead&partno=BLM15GG221SN1%23)

Comments? Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Schematic? What is your design goal?

Comment: Start with spectral PSRR and Load Reg step load specs then use s-parms for each part and verify performance or compute Zo to meet spec with spectral load and watch out for anti-resonance

Comment: Do those capacitors share vias? They must NOT share vias.